# How to fix the serial column in MS Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word

I can't make right alignment on this two number like rest.

I clicked right alignment so many times but numbers are staying there.

[image]

& also I can't use "continue numbering" properly after **15** it should give **16** but it gives me **17**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your file is corrupt, you should be able to reset the numbering by doing the following;

1. Select the column
2. Press delete to remove items not in the list
3. Select the column again
4. Click the numbering button to turn off the existing numbering
5. Click the numbering button again to turn numbering back on

This should give you new numbering in the table.